# switching letters to different letters inside a string (Caesar cipher)

Tags: python, string, encryption

I've got some homework involving Caesar cipher, and I got stuck here:
I need to write a function which gets a text (as a String) and a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the English ABC, and its values are other letters from the ABC.
My goal is to go over the text, and wherever there is a letter (only letters!)
change it to the value belongs to the specific letter in the dictionary.

edit: my function should return the deciphered text as a string.

Comment: The traditional response to a question like this is, "show us what you have done so far..."

Comment: Remember that you can iterate over strings, so something like `''.join(c for c in inputString)` will produce a new string (we haven't actually done any swapping in that example).  That might get you started.

Comment: i have got nothing by far. i'm still thinking how can i move the text into a list, or other stracture will allow me to change letters.

Comment: you need to accept some answers.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method:

```
>>> u"abc".translate({ord('a'): u'x', ord('b'): u'y', ord('c'): u'z'})
'xyz'
```

Look at [`maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) if you're using bytestrings or if your Python is older than 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of pseudocode (language agnostic). You should be able to take it from here.

```
cipher = array
caesar_mask = [ A: G, ... , Z: F ] 

for each letter_index in text
    cipher_letter = caesar_mask[text[letter_index]]
    cipher[] = cipher_letter
end
```

Answer (score 2):

First question is if you have to do it in place.

Then I would look into these things:

1. list comprehension
2. map()
3. how to iterate through letters in string
4. how to join a sequence of letters to create string
5. how to replace characters in string

Not in any specific order and not necesarily all inclusive.